# How to declare class attributes in swift, just like UITableViewCell reuse identifiers?

Tags: swift, reuseidentifier, class-attributes

I am trying to declare a reuse identifier associated to a UITableView subclass in swift.

From my understanding I would like to declare an class stored property (not an instance one) so i have access via: MyCustomTableCell.ReuseIdentifer.

Here is what I was trying:

```
class MyCustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    class let ReuseIdentifier = "MyCustomTableViewCellReuseIdentifier"

}
```

The compiler mentions that class attributes are not supported yet. How to declare such kind of constants associated to a class type in a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just as the compiler said, constants / variables cannot be declared at the class-level yet. The "yet" in the error is key: Apple does intend to add support for this feature, and if you wait a few Xcode releases, it should be available.